# Why doesn't "key=str.lower" turn the iterables lower case when sorting?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a line of code from: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

The code is:

```
>>> sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split(), key=str.lower)

Output: ['a', 'Andrew', 'from', 'is', 'string', 'test', 'This']
```

I understand `sort()` but in the above, for `key=str.lower` ; doesn't this make all of the iterables(words in this case) lower case? So why is `Andrew` and `This` still upper case? Or am I understanding this wrongly?

Comment: key is a criteria for sorting (comparing), it would not change the source data.

Comment: use `"This is a test string from Andrew".lower().split()` if you want return all lower case ( lower it before sorting)

Comment: Thanks SCKU, I just wanted to understand what key does- I know it is possible to omit the key argument? So what does it do in this case?

Comment: [_key_ specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, `key=str.lower`). The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted)

Comment: - compare the elements directly :) (from above link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split(), key=str.lower)
```

does not make the elements lower case. While doing the sort, it calls `lower()` on each element in a temporary variable, performs the sort according to the value of that temporary variable, and then throws it away. The behaviour you seem to expect would be what would happen with

```
>>> sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".lower().split())
```

The whole point of using `key=` is that it leaves unchanged the data to be sorted.

Think of `key=` as specifying "sorted as if". You use it when `sorted()`, left to itself, would put the words in a particular order that you don't want:

```
>>> sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split())
['Andrew', 'This', 'a', 'from', 'is', 'string', 'test']
```

This is surprising to novices because they don't understand why `T` sorts before `a`. The reason is that under the hood, letters are represented by numbers, called a collating sequence, and the capital letters come first in the collating sequence. So to tell `sorted()` this is not what you want, you have to provide a rule for ordering the words in the list: you want to say that `a` comes before `Andrew` which in turn comes before `from`: a case-insensitive sort. To do that, you tell `sorted()` to sort the words *as if they were all shifted into lowercase*. The function to do the downshift is `str.lower()` and so that is what you pass it using `key=`. You see it often with text data because a case-insensitive sort is generally more useful than a case-sensitive one.

But it is not the only thing you might want to do. Suppose for a moment you wanted to sort the words in the string by length. Then you would do

```
>>> sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split(), key=len)
['a', 'is', 'This', 'test', 'from', 'string', 'Andrew']
```

In this case, the function `len()` does the transformation on the data that you want before sorting: sorted *as if each word were replaced by the number of letters in it.*

And if your rule for determining the sort order is more complicated than that, then you can write your own function. If you were constructing a rhyming dictionary then you would want the words sorted by their endings. A simple function to do that transformation is:

```
def rev(s: str) -> str:
    return s[::-1]
```

Then you could get words in rhyming dictionary order like this:

```
>>> sorted("bring me the string from her locker".split(), key=rev)
['the', 'me', 'bring', 'string', 'from', 'her', 'locker']
```

Here `the` comes before `me` because `h` comes before `m` and `her` comes before `locker` because `h` comes before `k`.